# How to root Samsung Galaxy Ace II X

Tags: rooting, samsung, unrooting

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace II X smartphone, and for various reasons, would like to root it. It is running android version 4.0.4. How exactly do I root it? Should I download the necessary files, or make them myself? (I have no idea how to make them). I would also like to somehow have a way to undo the rooting if necessary, and have a backup of everything on my phone now. I have heard that rooting could cause my phone to become a "brick" or be completely useless, should I be concerned about this?

Also, my computer is a mac, if that makes any difference whatsoever in the rooting process.

Answer (score 1):

There are several root options for Samsung devices.

**EDIT: It seems like the first method is not available for your device.**

- [CF-Auto-Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1980683): Created by XDA developer Chainfire, this method consists of a modified recovery image which injects the `su` binary into the system and restores original recovery upon reboot. This is the safest method because it does not require user interaction.
- Root programs: These PC apps, like [OneClickRoot](http://www.oneclickroot.com/), require you to enable [USB debugging](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-usb-debugging-mode-on-android-makeuseof-explains/) and connect your phone to your PC. It will then execute an exploit which will allow it to inject `su` to `/system`.
- [Framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276): Created by XDA member alephzain, this is the only root method that does not require a PC. Once installed and opened, Framaroot will present you with a list of exploits compatible with your phone. Once you choose an exploit, Framaroot will either a) tell you that the exploit was successful and that you need to reboot in order to enjoy root, b) tell you that the exploit failed and that you should try another, or c) it used a so-called `local.prop` trick to root your device with a squashed file system, and that you should reboot to try and see if you have root.

All methods install a Superuser apps which governs the use of `su.`
An example of a su app is SuperSu, which has an unroot option in its settings tab.

As for the bricking, it's very hard to do that unless

- You interrupted a flash process
- You deleted something you shouldn't have
- You flashed something meant for another device

Answer (score 0):

Check out the XDA [FAQ thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2451967) for the Galaxy Ace II X.

After you thoroughly research rooting and its pros/cons, if you decide to root, the instructions are in that thread. Since you are on a Mac, you will not be able to use *Odin*, which is designed for Windows. You will have to use the Mac/Linux alternative, *JOdin*, as explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiPRXq207Ug). Good luck!

*Note: About* ***bricking*** *your device: I wouldn't worry about it, in all my years of rooting and tweaking, I have not had one brick. The only way to brick is to modify something you know you really shouldn't, unplug something while your bootloader is connected to your computer, or using a corrupted download for rooting/bootloader operations. Just use this general rule of thumb: Look on the XDA thread. If someone has done it and their phone is not dead, then it is typically safe to do.*